# How do I use the .getMonth() command with Google Contacts in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I am writing some code in Apps Script that loads all contacts from Google Contacts and now I need to get the birthday for these contacts. I have downloaded the exact code that is published on the Google Developers Site but I am getting a weird log that I cannot comprehend.
It works for .getDay() perfectly fine and then with .getMonth() it does not work.

**This is the code:**

```
var birthday = contacts[0].getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY)[0];
console.log(birthday.getDay());
console.log(birthday.getMonth());
```

**This is my log:**

```
22:22:53    Info    5
22:22:53    Info    Logging output too large. Truncating output. { toString: 
            [Function: toString],
             name: [Function: toString],
           toJSON: [Function: toString],
          ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
          JANUARY: 
                 { toString: [Function: toString],
                       name: [Function: toString],
              ...
```

Any help appreciated. I just want to output the number of the month

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
function getBirthDate1() {
  let bd = ContactsApp.getContactsByName("Bob Katz")[0];
  bd.getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY).forEach(e => {
    Logger.log(e.getDay());
    Logger.log(e.getMonth());
  });
}

Execution log
2:57:10 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:57:11 PM  Info    1.0
2:57:11 PM  Info    JANUARY
2:57:12 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```